# Firemonkey: How can I disable the scroll of a TWebBrowser?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, twebbrowser, delphi-10.1-berlin

I want to show a video from youtube in my form, so I put a TWebBrowser and linked to a youtube video, the video shows fine but the user can scroll the webBrowser. How can I block this function? I found nothing on the Object Inspector.

edit: I found this code: `WebBrowser1.OleObject.document.body.Scroll := 'no';` but looks like this is for desktop projects, not mobile... or I'm missing some Units on *uses*?

Comment: Don't do it that way. Take control of the HTML that the browser renders. Don't show the raw youtube page, craft your own page that embeds the video and nothing else.

Comment: "or I'm missing some Units on uses?" It's impossible for this to be the case. As David says, scrolling depends on the web page, not Delphi. The `TWebBrowser` completely wraps the platform's native browser. If a web page doesn't want you to scroll, they'll exclusively disable that ability. Otherwise, scrolling is enabled by default. Even if it wasn't for scrolling, you still don't want the user to see YouTube's search bar, menu, and related videos, right?